# Iterate over a table and perform logic based on a value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using a stored procedure for this, and obviously below isn't going to be my exact code, but an highly trimmed version to get the idea across. Please keep in mind that I actually have a lot of filtering done on this temporary table, so adding anything to the `CREATE TABLE` query would just be more of a hassle than anything.

```
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filtered_results AS (SELECT * FROM users);
  # Numerous filters removing stuff from the table.
END
```

For the purpose of this question, lets say that the tables structure is really simple, like so:

```
user_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

Now let's say that I have a question table with the following structure:

```
question_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY
user_id INT(11) 
text VARCHAR(40)
```

Now lets say I want to iterate over the table and check some other tables to filter the users that don't have at least 4 questions. So something like this:

```
for each row in filtered_results
    if count(question_id) < 4 where user_id = row.user_id in questions
        delete row
    end if
end loop
```

Comment: `delete from table where user_id in (select user_id from question group by  user_id having count(*) < 4)` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos - How would I go about getting the user_id from each row in the `filtered_results` table without iterating?

Comment: For example, 500 users my have questions, but if there's only 3 users in the `filtered_results` table, there's no reason to select and try to delete from ~500 users.

Comment: You don't need to create a table with your filtered result, it can be the select into the IN statement for the delete, the group by would be done on it as a subquery. What I posted as a comment is the Ideia since you didn't post the whole query. About the 3 users over 500, this is done by the group by statement, leave it to the Database engine, you don't need to worry how much lines it would select, depending on your structure you will running a statement once is better then 500 (for each user).

Comment: The query executes, however does not delete any values from the filtered results. I've checked to make sure that there is one user with `<4` questions and one with `>4`. Both users remain in the table. 

`delete from filtered_results WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM questions GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 4);`

Comment: Execute the subquery separatedelly to see if it returns any row, just this: `SELECT user_id FROM questions GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 4` If it returns it means that your table with the filtered result does not have any of the users that is returned from that query. I'm going to sleep now since it is really late here 1:00 am, If you still don't solve it I will help you tomorrow!

Comment: @JorgeCampos - The issue is that a user also may not have any questions, meaning there will be no present rows in the questions table. For example, Sally may have 3 questions so she is deleted. However bobby has 0 questions and remains in the `filtered_results` table, which is not the behavior I need. So basically I also need to delete every row where the user_id is not present in the questions table.

Comment: See my below answer. @huhushow there is no need to create a procedure with a temporary table and a cursor on it giving excess work to the database when you can just do it with one plain simple query.

Comment: @Hobbyist The answer I give helped?

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion and your last comment, I think I came up with a solution more elegant than running a cursor (as I previous mentioned in the comments).

You need to run a delete command into the results based on a `LEFT JOIN` of your `to_be_deleted_table` with your `questions` table. I'm taking into account that your `to_be_deleted_table` has the user_id on it.

Consider this sample:

```
create table filtered_results (
    user_id integer,
    name varchar(10)
);
insert into filtered_results values
 (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Sally'), (3, 'Cheer'), (4, 'Sid'), (5, 'Simon'), 
 (6, 'Lua'), (7, 'Liv'), (8, 'Taylor'), (9, 'Jay'), (10, 'Mike');

create table questions (
    question_id integer,
    user_id integer
);

insert into questions values 
 (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), 
 (6, 2), (7, 2), 
 (8, 3), (9, 3), (10, 3), (11, 3), 
 (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (15, 4), 
 (16, 5), (17, 5), (18, 5), (19, 5), 
 (20, 6), (21, 6), (22, 6), (23, 6), 
 (24, 7), (24, 7), (24, 7), (24, 7);
```

This sample has all what you said, users that have 4 (or more questions), users that have less than 4 questions and users that **don't** have questions at all.

The query to delete the users where they don't have at least 4 question will be:

```
delete 
  from filtered_results
 where user_id in 
     (select user_id
        from (select f.user_id
                from filtered_results f
                  LEFT JOIN questions q ON (f.user_id = q.user_id)
               group by f.user_id
               having count(*) < 4) a
     );
```

You must be wondering why I have two subselects, that is because you need to trick the compiler so you can delete the rows from the same table you are doing the select, in this example `filtered_results`.

If you want to delete from another table based on the user_id at the filtered table just do as follow:

```
delete 
  from users
 where user_id in 
     (select f.user_id
        from filtered_results f
          LEFT JOIN questions q ON (f.user_id = q.user_id)
       group by f.user_id
      having count(*) < 4
     );
```

Remember that if that is the case you don't need to create the `filtered_results` just use the query that you create it as a subquery in the first case I showed.

Hope it helps.

And if you want to see it working, take a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/843ea/1)

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work either for whatever reason, I ended up using an alteration of your method and doing a SELECT statement using the conditions at the end of all the filtering, thus still applying the filter.